# Where is Xcode's Build and Archive command looking for its iTunes artwork?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, itunesartwork

I just found out about the Build and Archive option, and it looks very nice.

However, my application build with Build and Archive has a big question mark as its artwork in the Organizer window, instead of my nice iTunesArtwork file. I tried to have it in my project as PNG, JPG, with or without extension.

I probably missed something simple. Any idea? Where is the Build and Archive command looking for its iTunes artwork?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time later spent experimenting, here is how "Build and Archive" cope with application icons, as far as I could see:

1- To have the icon show up in the organizer window, the icon must be listed in the application info.plist file in an CFBundleIconFiles entry. See [Technical Q&A QA1686](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1686.html) for the details.

This is not really related to iTunesArtwork though.

2- To have iTunes show the application artwork, it needs to find a PNG file named `iTunesArtwork` (no extension). Supposedly, this file needs to be at the root level of the `.ipa` file. However, iTunes will also be happy to find `iTunesArtwork` in the application bundle itself, deeper in the `.ipa` file.

3- Now to answer the precise question:

- Q: Where does "Build and Archive" look for the `iTunesArtwork` file to include in the .ipa file?
- A: It doesn't. If you want iTunesArtwork for iTunes, you need to include it in the target application bundle. It's wasteful, but iTunes will find it anyway.

At least, I wasn't able to have `Build and Archive` use my `iTunesArtwork` file at all. The only way to have it at all that I could find is to include it in the application bundle.

To do so, include it in your project *and* make sure it's included with the application target build items.

It's wasteful, because it needlessly uses disk space on the device after installation.

Answer (score 1):

To get the icon to show in the Organiser, from a Build & Analyse, include the "Icon file" key with a value of just "Icon.png" or whatever your image is called. Don't include the double quotes. Include this in addition to the "Icon Files" key described in [Technical Q&A QA1686](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1686.html).